# Why does a dialogue's parent window not have the dialogue as a child?

Tags: win32gui

I've noticed that in most (if not all) applications in Windows, a dialogue doesn't have a bidirectional reference relative to its parent.  I.e. The parent of the dialogue doesn't appear to have a reference to the dialogue in the child window list.  I've noticed this before but now its really bugging me.  Is this by design?  Is there a way to get the handle to a window's dialogue(s) (one if modal, one or more if non-modal), given only the window's handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confusing *parent* with *owner*.  There is a distinction between a [*child* window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#child) and an [*owned* window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows).  Both are established using either `SetParent()` or the `hwndParent` parameter of `CreateWindow/Ex()`, but the difference is that an *owned* window is a top-level overlapped/popup window that does not have the `WS_CHILD` style flag (except for a few top-level windows that are owned by the system).  Child windows can be enumerated using `EnumChildWindows()`, whereas there is no single API to enumerate owned windows. You would have to use `EnumWindows()` to enumerate top-level windows, using `GetParent()`/`GetWindow(GW_OWNER)` to check if each window is owned by a specific owner.